# Using html-tags within HTMTL::link_to_route()

Tags: html, routes, laravel

In Laravel, how can I use html-tags when linking to a route via `HTML::link_to_route()`?

Example of what I have:

```
<li>
    {{ HTML::link_to_route( "books_new", "New Book" ) }}
</li>
```

What I would like to do:

```
<li>
    {{ HTML::link_to_route( 
"books_new", 
"<span class='icon-book'></span>New Book" 
    ) }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear - but you cannot pass html via link_to_route.

The problem is the output from the HTML class is escaped automatically. So if you try to pass this:

```
{{ HTML::link_to_route('author','<img src="'.URL::base().'assets/images/image.jpg" alt="icon" />')) }}
```

it comes out like this:

```
&lt;img src=&quot;http://laravel3.dev/assets/images/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;icon&quot; /&gt;
```

which will just be text on the screen - no image. Instead you need to use `URI::to_route('author')` and generate the link yourself. So make a helper a like this (not tested):

```
function link_to_route_image($route, $image)
{
   $m = '<a href="'.URL::to_route($route).'">'
      . '<img>'.$image.'</img>'
      . '</a>';
   return $m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! I now use `<a href="{{ URL::to_route( "books_new" ) }}"><span class="icon-book"></span>New Book</a>`.

Comment: I was searching for something like this and thought my self that this should works based on link_to_route combination and URL::to_route. but it's not the case. It looks like they updated this in new version so now proper solution would be something like this {{ URL::route('profile.show', ['profile' => Auth::user()->username]) }} this for example links to user profile but to_route is changed in route only now.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this?

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ URL::to_route('books_new') }}"><span class='icon-book'></span>New Book</a>
</li>
```

If you're using "Font Awesome", just adding the class to anchor tag as someone mentioned would be fine for most cases because "Icon classes are echoed via CSS :before". You might need a bit of adjustment in CSS; but it might be better in terms of semantic mark-up.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('empdelete', array('id' => $employee->id)) }}">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/tick-red.jpg') }}" alt="DRC" id="DRCS-logo" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have HTML markup with `HTML::....` (class) , in the documentation they say that anything that is passed as a parameter to the class is escaped with an HTML entity function to make front-end safer!

Answer (score 0):

You can include font awesome or icon into Laravel Blade Template using this code, i already use and work perfect.

```
<a href="{{ route('member.edit',$data->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "Font Awesome", just adding the class to anchor tag as someone mentioned would be fine for most cases because "Icon classes are echoed via CSS :before".

So this is working for me:

```
<li>
    {{ HTML::link_to_route( "books_new", "New Book", null, ['class' => 'fa fa-edit'] ) }}
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

So far as I know, Laravel doesn't allow you to do that. To me, it seems out of standards.

Rather, apply a class called `icon-book` to your anchor tag, and then use the class to put the icon inside your anchor as a 'background-image`.

```
HTML::link_to_route('books_new', 'New Book', array('class' => 'icon-book'))
```

Alternatively:

1. Insert the `span` tag inside the `li` tag
2. Assign the `icon-book` class to the `li` tag

Comment: In addition, it might be of convenience to note that the new Laravel 4 (currently in beta) has scrapped support for the `HTML` class. They did it for a reason. Nonetheless, there are packages on Packagist if you would still like to use it if/when you upgrade to Laravel 4.